# How to center a menu on my online shop?

Tags: html, css

I hope I am right here, I need your help with my upcoming online shop. I would like to center the main categorie menu on the top but I am missing the right CSS order.

[This is what it looks right right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bid3.jpg) and there are 2 ways I want to test the looking.

First I want is a centered menu where *"home"* and *"Kollektionen"* have the same distance to the left or right.
And secondly I want to try out what it looks like when every li-element 'pushes' the next element to the right so that it's centered at the last one.

You know what I mean? 2 different ways of centering my menu and I don't find the right command....

I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

PS: sorry for my bad english, it's not my native language.

**EDIT:** I cannot post code I'm afraid as it's not mine. But maybe this is enough: the basic template is made of this http://www.shopwaredemo.de/

**2nd EDIT:** *after trying Asko's, Mike's and Tom's answer and both works I ask myself why? What is the difference between display:flex and display:inline-box and between text-align and justify-content set to center???*

Comment: please post the code which you tried.. it will be helpful for us to help you.

Comment: We need some code, screenshot is not enough (or link to the webpage if possible)

Comment: we need your current HTML and CSS code to see what can be done

Comment: I edited my post, is [THIS link](http://www.shopwaredemo.de/) enough for you to see the source code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps use `display: inline-block`? E.g the following:

```
.menu {
  text-align: center;
}

.menu li {
  float: none; /* assuming the template has set this to 'left' */
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px; /* tweak this for the space inbetween items */
  margin-right: 20px; /* and this, too */
}
```

Note that I didn't look at the code, so the div `.menu` is an example.

Comment: yeay, wow this kind of works! Thanks a lot. But the left margin of my home is further away than the last li to the right. Can I "auto-align" them somehow?

Comment: This might be because of the font-size bug, try .menu { font-size: 0; } and .menu li { font-size: 13px; /* or whatever you want */ }

Comment: font-size bug? Setting it the way you told me to didn't work - sorry :(

Comment: So just tweak the last li then, `.menu li:last-child { margin-left: 0; /* whatever will work */ }`

Comment: Okay, thank you a lot! So now you solved my 1st idea :) the menu is centered and left and right have the same distance. Can you also tell me how I can manage to enlarge every li-element so every element has the same size no matter how long the words are and it centeres itself?

Comment: No problem. For the next thing you need to figure out an average width for every element then, but I'll just put an example size (150px). Try this: `.menu li { min-width: 150px; text-align: center; }`. This way all elements are 150px in size, unless one of them is longer than 150px in which case that one particular element gets wider.

Comment: Hm...min-width does not seem to work :/ I also tried using !important because it might be overwritten anywhere else, but didn't work either. I seem to be too dumb :D

Comment: Perhaps the width is defined, which overwrites the min-width. Eg. `min-width: 150px; width: auto !important;`. If that doesn't work then just do `width: 150px !important;`, but note that the last way if the text is longer than 150px, it will break things. You can of course change the width to 200px or so if that will help.

Comment: okay, thanks! My working shift ends now, but I will consider your ideas and try it out tomorrow :) thanks a lot and I might reply again tomorrow!!!

Comment: It's done and finished...thanks a lot again - finally working the way I want! *thumps up*

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make the `<ul>` `display: inline-block` and apply `text-align: center` on parent.

JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2hSv/1/

Comment: thank you, this worked as well. Thanks as well for the example on JSFiddle. Same to you: the left margin of my home-element is further away than the last li to the right. Can I "auto-align" them somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing some code, maybe this will help.

```
.topmenu {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}
.menuitems {
    float: left;
    width: // Here you take the number of items divided by 100%
         // remember to take borders and margins into account
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependent on your browser scope you could use display:flex;

HTML:

```
<nav>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Neuheiten</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Orschmuck</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Ringe</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Halsketten</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Armbander</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Kollecktion</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
  background: #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

Example http://codepen.io/tom-maton/pen/AFpnJ

Comment: wow this works, TOO!? why are there so many ways of solving my problem. What is the difference between your answer and the one using text-align: center?

Comment: In addition to your solution, is there a possibility to let every li-element have the same size (by "pushing" the next element to to right) so they are centered in the end?

Comment: Thank you, but I'm afraid I cannot see your example!? It just opens codepen itself O:)

Comment: Whoops just updated the path.

Also just updated my earlier comment:
Yep its possible, just updated code example. Each li is set to 130px and it's always centered in the nav. It takes the center point of the UL and centers in the nav.

Comment: okay, thanks! My working shift ends now, but I will consider your ideas and try it out tomorrow :) thanks a lot and I might reply again tomorrow!!!

Comment: It's done and finished...thanks a lot again - finally working the way I want! *thumps up*

Answer (score 0):

back to work and managed to achieve my goal:

Thanks again for every answer, I used and played a lot with your snippets and and I ended up using this [(click click!)](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LnKhx):

```
#mainNavigation {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 98%;
}

#mainNavigation ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#mainNavigation li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 15%;
  text-align: center; /* to center the li-elements itself */
}
```

which works perfectly! Still figuring out what excatly *justify-center* and *display:flex* do but I want you to know that you helped a lot.

**CHEERS!**

---

*PS: how come my thread got a negative rating? it says -1 to me!? Did I do anything wrong?*